# Is there a problem with eating Gummy Bears and Meat together?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, fish

Most kosher gummy bears (and other gummy candy) that I have seen contain fish gelatin. Since there is a warning in the Shulchan Aruch against eating fish and meat together, does the same apply to something like a gummy bear?

p.s. I am not planning on putting candy on my sandwich, just curious.

Comment: +1 for specifying that you aren't going to eat a gummy bear and roast beef sandwich.

Comment: @WadCheber well... http://www.foodbeast.com/news/israel-heinz/

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67692

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an answer from The [Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-palate-gelatin.htm).

> Similarly fish gelatin in order to be considered kosher must be produced from kosher species of fish. The use of fish gelatin with meat foods poses an interesting question. As we have mentioned the Shulchan Aruch (Yore Deah:116) prohibits cooking meat and fish together because of health concerns. When dealing with possible health concerns we are more stringent than with possible Issur (prohibited substances). For this reason there is a question among the commentaries if the nullification in sixty rule applies to unhealthy substances as it does with prohibited substances. The custom is that one can nullify unhealthy substances in sixty (see Nekudas Hakesef, Yoreh Deah:116 & Pische' Tshuvah).
>
> Today there are many reasons for leniency in the use of fish gelatin
> together with meat. Many rabbinic authorities are of the opinion that
> the nature of some foods have changed, making the mixture of meat and
> fish no longer unhealthy (see Magen Avrohom Orach Chaim 173:1, Tshuvos
> Chasm Sofer vol:1 #101) In addition there is reason to say that not
> all fish are dangerous with meat. It may be that only the type
> mentioned in the Gemora (Binita) is unhealthy (see Pische' Tshuvah,
> Yoreh Deah 116:3). There is also good reason to say that the unhealthy
> aspects of fish cooked with meat are found in the flesh of the fish,
> not in their skin and bone (from which gelatin is made). Gelatin does
> not have fish flavor. As such it may not harbor the harmful effects
> that fish carry (see Pische Tshuva ,Tshuvos Sride Eish vol:2 #67 re.
> cooking beef in fish oil). With this same reasoning we can say that
> gelatin can be batel (nullified) with a majority of other food
> ingredients and can be mixed with meat. (As stated according to R'
> Aharon Kotler, zt"l regarding animal gelatin & milk) As a result of
> these reasons it is acceptable to use fish gelatin with meat. We may
> use much the same reasoning in the reverse case, to allow animal
> gelatin with fish.

Note that the language here is based in "leniency" and "it is acceptable" so this is not an unequivocal endorsement. CYLOR.

Comment: +1 Both the Mishna Berurah and Aruch HaShulchan quote that Magen Avraham, it can be assumed their intention is to rule like him. Modern archaic practice notwithstanding.

Comment: "It is acceptable" sounds to me pretty close to an unequivocal endorsement, albeit one that required sufficient halachic reasoning.

Comment: Most importantly, why would Maamid be relevant to a Sakana?